# Heroku: Disable Autoscaling programmatically?

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

Is there a way to disable/re-enable Heroku autoscaling programmatically via API / CLI / rules (e.g. time of day?)

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be any way to do this programatically. [The documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#configuration) only references the Heroku Dashboard and the [Platform API documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) doesn't reference autoscaling.

You might be able to toggle scaling on and off if use a third-party scaling tool like [HireFire](https://www.hirefire.io/) or [Adept Scale](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/adept-scale), but you'll have to evaluate those options to see if they do everything you need within your budget.

Comment: thanks. I did not find a way to programatically disable/re-enable even using HireFire/Adept Scale. Can you point to whether/where this can be done using those tools?

Comment: @sellarafaeli, I'm not sure. If you can't find a way to do it within the tool I guess you could add and delete the Adept Scale addon using the platform API?